# The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr spfx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am experiencing this problem when using the
 `gulp bundle --ship`  command.
I have searched the internet and I really don't know what to do. Please help me

[image]

Comment: Try adding warning suppression as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968594/gulp-bundle-ship-the-build-failed-because-a-task-wrote-output-to-stderr/52001214) or [here](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/spfx-exception-gulp-bundle-the-build-failed-because-a-task-wrote-output-to-stderr/). Let me know if it works for you. Also, if command is bundling the package with these warnings, you can ignore these warnings and package the solution, https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2131

Answer (score 0):

The error shown above means that somewhere in your code you are using a function expression, like this example:

```
var sum = function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

And typescript wants you to re-write it like this:

```
let sum = (x: number, y: number): number => {
    return x + y;
}
```

The => symbol is the "arrow function" notation that typescript wants you to use instead of the function expression.

You can see in the error message above what lines in your .tsx file it is erroring on: 63 and 104.  If you need help with how to re-write your code using arrow notation, you can comment here and we can try to help.